# How to change CSS of directly adjacent sibling elements on hover via JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i would like to change the css style of directly adjacent siblings of a hovered element, so if i hover element 4, elements 3 and 5 should get a new css class added.

Here is a JSfiddle with the expected result and what i got so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/uxa49myL/5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("h1").hover(function() {
    $(this).nextSibling.addClass("siblings");
    $(this).previousSibling.addClass("siblings");
  });
});
```

sadly, the nextSibling and previousSibling jquery functions do not work as i expected.

Comment: You can do using .prev() and .next()  Like $(this).prev().addClass("siblings");
    $(this).next().addClass("siblings");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.next` and `.prev` methods of jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("h1").hover(function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("siblings")
    $(this).next().addClass("siblings");
    $(this).prev().addClass("siblings");
  });
});
```

```css
.siblings {
  color:green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>C</h1>
<h1>A</h1>
<h1>B</h1>
```

Comment: They will also need to remove the `siblings` class at the start, otherwise gradually everything will gain that class. (Also, the `addClass()` the asker had is probably better than setting the props, as you may be overwriting any existing classes)

Comment: my man, thank you :) i was able to get the result i wanted. thanks to DBS too, i added a line to remove all siblings classes from h1 elements before adding it to the adjacent elements. thanks guys.
https://media.giphy.com/media/ZOln4JxCoZay4/giphy.gif

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use the `.next()` and `.prev()` JQuery call to get the adjacent siblings.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("h1").hover(function(){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("siblings");
    $(this).next().addClass("siblings");
    $(this).prev().addClass("siblings");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `next` and `prev` jQuery to target the next and previous sibling. And use `siblings` to target all the sibling elements.

Also you will need to remove the `siblings` class from `h1` on mouse out.

Remove the margins form the `h1` and use `padding` instead to avoid the flickering issue.

Also you are using `container-inner` id twice which is not a best practice. Use class instead

```js
$("h1").hover(function() {
  $(this).siblings().removeClass("siblings")
  $(this).next().addClass("siblings")
  $(this).prev().addClass("siblings");
}, function() {
  $("h1").removeClass("siblings")
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.container-inner {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  transition: ease all .3s;
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 6px 0;
}

h1:hover {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.siblings {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='container'>
  <div class="container-inner">
    expected result:
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/RJS2kHM.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="container-inner">
    result:<br><br>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```